# Changing a Custom Data Generator input size from 3 channels to 1

Tags: python, deep-learning, vgg-net

Im creating a custom data generator for a deep learning model where the input is an RGB image. I want to grayscale this image and merge the 3 color channels, any idea on how to do this?
'''
class CustomDataGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

```
def __init__(self, binary, track,
             batch_size=32,
             input_size=(32, 224, 396, 3)):
  
    self.binary = open(binary, "rb")
    self.track = open(track, "r")
    self.data = [line.split(",") for line in self.track]
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.input_size = input_size

def __getitem__(self, index):
    self.binary.seek(int(self.data[index][0]))
    input_data = self.binary.read(int(self.data[index][1].strip()))
    input_data = np.frombuffer(input_data, dtype = np.float32 )
    input_data = np.resize(input_data, self.input_size)

    self.binary.seek(int(self.data[index][2]))
    output_data = self.binary.read(int(self.data[index][3].strip()))
    output_data = np.frombuffer(output_data, dtype = np.float32 )
    output_data = np.resize(output_data, (self.batch_size, 4))        
    return input_data, output_data

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data)
```

'''